pd.to_datetime fails with old dates
I have a csv file with very old dates, and pd.to_datetime fails. It works in polars. Is this an inherent limitation in pandas, a bug or something else?
import pandas as pd
dates = ["12/31/1672","12/31/1677","10/19/2024"]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
df
        Date
0        NaT
1 1677-12-31
2 2024-10-19

in polars
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({   'Date': dates})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('Date').str.strptime(pl.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
df
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ Date       │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 1672-12-31 │
│ 1677-12-31 │
│ 2024-10-19 │
└────────────┘


See here. Both of the links in the answer are dead now and I have to go out now so won't be able to track them down but hopefully it gives you a start

pandas has timestamp limitations; the docs suggests use of period for such cases (of course it depends if the period data type covers your use case):
df.assign(new_dates=pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date, freq='D'))
         Date   new_dates
0  12/31/1672  1672-12-31
1  12/31/1677  1677-12-31
2  10/19/2024  2024-10-19

